# Getting the coordinates of a touched item inside a gridview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gridview, android-touch-event

I have a `gridview`that contains some items. I want to get the screen related coordinates when touching any item in the grid.

I know I can do that using `MotionEvent.getRawX` and `MotionEvent.getRawY`. The problem is that I cannot set the touch listener on the item inside the grid, it doesn't fire, I don't know why. I've tried to set the listener for the gridview itself, this works, but once I touch any item the callback gets called more than once (2-4 times). Here is my code:

```
public class Calibration extends Activity {

    List<String> list;
    GridView grid; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calibration_activity);

        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);


        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("6");
        list.add("7");
        list.add("8");
        list.add("9");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
        grid.setAdapter(adp);




    /*Working but appears 2-4 times*/
        grid.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "( " + motionEvent.getRawX() + ", " + motionEvent.getRawY() + ")",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/gridView1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:numColumns="auto_fit"
          android:background="#7CFC00"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:columnWidth="100dp"
          android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Notice that my aim is to have `ImageView` inside the `gridView` not string values. I tried having the ImageView filled in the adapter, then setting the listener on it, but that didn't work. So, I'm just using String values as an example for this question.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your onTouch method to show the toast only when user's finger left the the gridview (ACTION_UP)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if(motionEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "( " + motionEvent.getRawX() + ", " + motionEvent.getRawY() + ")",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

You can try to check other KeyEvent conditions such as ACTION_DOWN. This is up to you

Doc is [HERE](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN)

`ACTION_DOWN` -> the key has been pressed down.

`ACTION_MULTIPLE`-> you are pressing and sliding thru the screen (this event is sent until user release the screen)

`ACTION_UP` -> the key has been released.

Comment: Thank you Guilherme P for your useful answer, I need sometime to try the solution. I will try it and let you know. But, can you please tell me why the callback was called multiple times? Is it because multiple events happen simultaneously? Thanks.